# Generics in overridden methods

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Ran into an interesting issue; the following class compiles:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        foo(a);
        foo(b);
    }   

    private static void foo(A a) {
        System.out.println("In A");
    }   

    private static void foo(B b) {
        System.out.println("In B");
    }   

    private static class A {}

    private static class B extends A {}

}
```

but this one fails:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A<String> a = new A<>();
        B b = new B();

        foo(a);
        foo(b);
    }   

    private static void foo(A<String> a) {
        System.out.println("In A");
    }   

    private static void foo(B b) {
        System.out.println("In B");
    }   

    private static class A<T> {}

    private static class B extends A {}

}
```

with this error:

```
Test.java:8: error: reference to foo is ambiguous, both method foo(A<String>) in Test and method foo(B) in Test match              
        foo(b);                                                                                                                    
        ^                                                                                                                          
Note: Test.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.                                                                               
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                                                                                 
1 error
```

I'd have thought that due to type erasure that these would be essentially identical.  Any one know what's going on here?

Comment: What is that `A<String> a = new A<>();`? How about `A<String> a = new A<String>();`?

Comment: @Trinimon That's just Java7 shorthand notation for A<String> a = new A<String>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the dawn of generics, Java had methods like

```
public class Collections

    public void sort(List list) {...}               [1]
```

And user code may have things like

```
public class MyList implements List ...             [2]

MyList myList = ...;
Collections.sort(myList);                           [3]
```

When generics was added to Java, a decision was made to convert *existing* classes and methods to generic ones, without breaking any code using them. That is a great achievement in terms of difficulty, at the great price of leaving the language complicated and flawed.

So `[1]` was generified, but `[3]` must still compile as is, without having to generify `[2]`.

The hack is in [§15.12.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3)

> Ai can be converted by method invocation conversion (§5.3) to Si

basically saying that if the argument type (Ai) is raw, then erase the parameter type (Si) too for the purpose of matching.

Back to your example, we see why `foo(A<String>)` is considered applicable for `foo(b)`.

However there's another question - is `foo(A<String>)` applicable per [§15.12.2.2]? The answer seems to be "no" by the letter of the spec. But it may be a bug of the spec.

Comment: Right, foo(A<String>) is purposely applicable for calling with an argument of type B for backwards compatibility.  The odd part is how this logic is interacting with the logic specified in 15.12.2.5 so that foo(B) is no longer considered maximally specific for the foo(b) invocation.

Comment: well, `B` is not a subtype of `A<String>`, therefore `foo(B)` is not more specific than `foo(A<String>)`

Comment: So, the oddity is really that B is considered a subtype of A<String> for method invocation purposes (for bw compat) but not for the purposes of determining the most-specific method?  I think I need to re-read the spec again, that seems like a really odd way to handle the situation.

Comment: the spec is not very well written on raw types.

Comment: Agreed. Looking at the JLS again, I think this is how it's written.  The compatibility hack looks to be in 15.12.2.2 (Ai is convertible to some type Ci by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9), and Ci <: Si.) but 15.12.2.5 (choosing the most specific method) doesn't contain any language about unchecked conversions (handling raw types).  I'd almost argue that this is a bug in the spec.  Anyways, thanks for the help in getting to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is that you are mixing generics and raw types (B should be declared like `class B<T> extends A<T>` or `class B extends A<SomeType>`).

The actual reason why this is happening is buried somewhere in [the JLS, section #15.12.2.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7) and following - good luck to articulate it succintly ;-)

Comment: Same comments as for @Louis' answer. That change isn't sufficient on its own.

Comment: I think section [#15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) might be more applicable here.  The compiler isn't trying to infer a type; it's trying to decide which method to invoke.  It seems to me that the question should be, why doesn't the compiler think that `foo(B)` is more specific than `foo(A<String>)`, given that it knows `b` is of type `B`?

Comment: I looks like it's likely some combination of those specs, 15.12.2.5 references the types infered using the process in 15.12.2.7.  Digging through those I'm definitly not a fan of their notation though - seems they could have chosen something a little more expressive.

Comment: @matts Yes indeed it boils down to finding out if one method is more specific than the other, which depends on 15.2.2.7 when generics are involved. To be honest I have not looked in details as it is a real mess.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static class B extends A {}
```

You're omitting the type arguments for `A` here.  What you probably mean is

```
private static class B<T> extends A<T> {}
```

Additionally, `B b = new B()` has no `<String>` argument, either; you must do

```
B<String> b = new B<String>();
```

...And, finally,

```
private static void foo(B b) {
    System.out.println("In B");
}
```

should be something like

```
private static void foo(B<String> b) {
    System.out.println("In B");
}
```

In general, if there's a type `Foo` that has a generic argument, `Foo` should basically *always* have a type argument.  In this particular case, `class B extends A` didn't have a type argument for `A`, then `B` needed a type argument, so you needed a type argument everywhere you mentioned `B`.  (The one major exception to that rule is `instanceof` expressions, but you don't have any here.)

Comment: Yeah, referencing a parametrized type without specifying a type parameter is definitely a no-no.  I ran into this working with some old classes extending java.util collection interfaces that were never updated to handle generics.  The question was more about what's different in the type inference rules when generics are applied to A.